# aws application load balancer target group has no 'registered' target but cannot assign ECS fargate cluster because it doesn't have valid ipv4?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elb

I have a terraform-defined ECS cluster with fargate task, service, target group and lb.

I'm trying to send requests to the fargate cluster but it's timing out. I've tried to add an attachment as follows:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "websocket-server" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.websocket-server.arn
  target_id        = aws_ecs_cluster.websocket-server-cluster.id
  port             = 443
}
```

But unfortunately this throws:

```
Error registering targets with target group: ValidationError: The IP address 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:xxxxxx:cluster/websocket-server-cluster' is not a valid IPv4 address
```

My LB/target group/ECS definitions:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "websocket-server-cluster" {
  name = "websocket-server-cluster"
}


resource "aws_ecs_service" "websocket-server-service" {
  name                               = "websocket-server-service"
  cluster                            = aws_ecs_cluster.websocket-server-cluster.arn
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 200
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 0
  launch_type                        = "FARGATE"
  task_definition                    = aws_ecs_task_definition.websocket-server-task.arn

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.websocket-server.arn
    container_name   = "websocket-server"
    container_port   = 443
  }

  network_configuration {
    assign_public_ip = true
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.public.id, aws_security_group.private.id]
    subnets          = [aws_subnet.public.id, aws_subnet.private.id]
  }

}

module "websocket-server" {
  source           = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-ecs-container-definition.git?ref=tags/0.58.1"
  container_name   = "websocket-server"
  container_image  = "${aws_ecr_repository.websocket-server.repository_url}:latest"
  container_cpu    = "256"
  container_memory = "512"
  port_mappings = [
    {
      containerPort = 443
      hostPort      = 443
      protocol      = "tcp"
    }
  ]

  environment = []


}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "websocket-server-task" {
  family                   = "websocket-server"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  memory                   = "512"
  cpu                      = "256"
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.ecs-container-role.arn
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs-container-role.arn
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  container_definitions    = module.websocket-server.json_map_encoded_list
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags, tags_all
    ]
  }
}


resource "aws_lb" "main" {
  name                       = "main"
  internal                   = false
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  security_groups            = [aws_security_group.public.id, aws_security_group.private.id]
  enable_deletion_protection = false
  subnets                    = [aws_subnet.public.id, aws_subnet.public-backup.id]
}


resource "aws_lb_target_group" "websocket-server" {
  name        = "websocket-server"
  port        = 443
  protocol    = "HTTPS"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id
  target_type = "ip"

  health_check {
    enabled             = true
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 3
    timeout             = 10
    protocol            = "HTTPS"
    path                = "/apis/websocket-server/health"
    interval            = "100"
    matcher             = "200"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.main
  ]

}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "websocket-server" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = aws_acm_certificate.main.arn


  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.websocket-server.arn
    type             = "forward"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "http" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}



resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "main" {
  listener_arn    = aws_lb_listener.websocket-server.arn
  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.main.arn
}
```

Comment: A cluster does not really make any sense as a target to begin with, particularly for a fargate cluster... Consider many services can run in a single cluster -- what would would you expect to happen here? Also fargate services only run in AWS VPC interfaces, so it's not like you have host ports to target, either. What leads you to believe you need to define a tg attachment in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attachment definition is not necessary at all. Keep in mind, containers for Fargate services do not use network interfaces of the underlying EC2 instances in the cluster (you don't see the instances at all for that matter). They use AWS VPC networking mode only -- independent network interfaces in the VPC are attached to the containers.

The target group attachment happens automatically and is configured through the `load_balancer` block in the `aws_ecs_service` resource. As ECS starts the containers, they get registered with the target group automatically. There is no static attachment to define in the case of Fargate ECS services.

Just remove the tg attachment resource from your tf file altogether.

Check out [this resource](https://engineering.finleap.com/posts/2020-02-20-ecs-fargate-terraform/) for a decent reference implementation with terraform.

---

As a completely separate side note, you *probably* also do ***not*** want `assign_public_ip = true` in your service configuration. That would allow access to your containers directly without going through the load balancer which is almost never what you want when you're using a load balancer.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation and the extra advice. Unfortunately I'm getting to the conclusion that my ALB isn't even accessible from the internet, no requests showing up under 'monitoring' so probably my VPC configuration is wrong. 

Do you know if it is enough to have the `10.0.0.0/18` on the CIDR block?

Comment: @SebastianG You'll need a few different things for internet connectivity. You'll need a public subnet with an internet gateway, a private subnet for your cluster and services, and your ALB must be in the same AZ(s) as your cluster. The ALB will be assigned to both the public and private subnet. The CIDR range doesn't matter much as long as the subnet mask is `/27` or "lower" (so yours is fine there). A NAT gateway will also be required in your private subnet if your services must reach the internet independent of return traffic to the ALB. Finally, security groups must allow traffic needed